# Get value from other column based on value of a column

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

For each row in a data frame I want to copy a value from one column to another depending on a value in third column.

I tried to do it with a combined for loop and if function:

```
    ## example

condition <- c("1","2","2","1","2","","3","3")
SZ01 <- c("1","1","1","1","1","","1","1")
SZ02 <- c("2","2","2","2","2","","2","2")
SZ03 <- c("3","3","3","3","3","","3","3")


df <- data.frame(cbind(condition,SZ01,SZ02,SZ03), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df$retribution <- NULL
df$special_prevention <- NULL
df$general_prevention <- NULL


for (i in 1:length(df$condition)){ 

  if (df$condition[i] == 1){

    df$retribution[i] <- df$SZ01[i]
    df$special_prevention[i] <- df$SZ02[i]
    df$general_prevention[i] <- df$SZ03[i]


  }else if (df$condition[i] == 2) {

    df$retribution[i] <- df$SZ02[i]
    df$special_prevention[i] <- df$SZ03[i]
    df$general_prevention[i] <- df$SZ01[i]

  }else if (df$condition[i] == 3) {

    df$retribution[i] <- df$SZ03[i]
    df$special_prevention[i] <- df$SZ01[i]
    df$general_prevention[i] <- df$SZ02[i]

  } else {
    df$retribution[i] <- "missing_condition"
    df$special_prevention[i] <- "missing_condition"
    df$general_prevention[i] <- "missing_condition"

  }
}
```

This seems to work (no error message), but looking at my data there must be something wrong.

For example row 1 has `condition == 1`. This means, that for this row `df$retribution` should receive the same value as the one in row 1 of `df$SZ01`.

But it doesn't. Is there anyone that can see the mistake I made?

Comment: Can you add an example of your initial data.frame and of your desired output?

Comment: does it make more sense now to you? unfortunately i dont know how to add tables into the text...

Comment: In case you want to add a table, you can simply paste the result of the command `dput(df)`, where `df` is the data frame you want to display.

Comment: The issue is that `condition, SZ01, SZ02, SZ03` are all factors. Do a `str(df)` to see that and use `df <- data.frame(cbind(condition,SZ01,SZ02,SZ03), stringsAsFactor=FALSE)` to correct.

Comment: thanks for the comments - i changed it that way... but still my code (and the code below) does not work :-/

Comment: You say "row 1 has condition == 1. This means, that for this row df$retribution should receive the same value as the one in row 1 of df$SZ01. But it doesn't" -- actually, though, `df$retribution[1]` and `df$SZ01[1]` are both 1 after your code above

Comment: Also, you are comparing the character "1" with the numeric value 1. `"1" == 1` evaluates to `TRUE` but you should be careful not to mix types by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
condition <- c("1","2","2","1","2","","3","3")
SZ01 <- c("1","1","1","1","1","","1","1")
SZ02 <- c("2","2","2","2","2","","2","2")
SZ03 <- c("3","3","3","3","3","","3","3")


df <- data.frame(cbind(condition,SZ01,SZ02,SZ03), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$retribution <- ifelse(df$condition == "1", df$SZ01,
                         ifelse(df$condition == "2", df$SZ02,
                            ifelse(df$condition == "3", df$SZ03, "missing")))

df$special_prevention <- ifelse(df$condition == "1", df$SZ02, 
                                ifelse(df$condition == "2", df$SZ03,
                                       ifelse(df$condition == "3", df$SZ01, "missing")))

df$general_prevention <- ifelse(df$condition == "1", df$SZ03, 
                                ifelse(df$condition == "2", df$SZ01,
                                       ifelse(df$condition == "3", df$SZ02, "missing"))))
```

Output:

```
df
  condition SZ01 SZ02 SZ03 retribution special_prevention general_prevention
1         1    1    2    3           1                  2                  3
2         2    1    2    3           2                  3                  1
3         2    1    2    3           2                  3                  1
4         1    1    2    3           1                  2                  3
5         2    1    2    3           2                  3                  1
6                              missing            missing            missing
7         3    1    2    3           3                  1                  2
8         3    1    2    3           3                  1                  2
```

Comment: It's a bit vague. Do you get an error? Is the output from my code above what you would expect to be correct?

Comment: yes thats the output I want to get... and I expected the same output with my code too.... I don't get any error message but all values in the new variables (retribution, special_prevention, general_prevention) are the value "2"

Comment: I was having the same problem, it's probably due to the fact that some of the variables are factors. Convert the four initial variables to characters and it should work. I will change the code slightly to make it more consistent.

Comment: that's what I did as well... but it didn't work yesterday. However, today it did. so apparently that's been the problem! thanks a lot for your help